# Как использовать RoundedDrawable в проекте?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Как использовать в проекте? Что подключить в Gradle можно для android.support.wear.widget.RoundedDrawable ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^"

Answer (score 1):

В описании компонента указан артефакт Maven, к которому он принадлежит:

> belongs to Maven artifact com.android.support:wear:28.0.0-alpha1

Соответственно, в зависимости build.gradle модуля нужно добавить:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0-rc01'
```

Либо использовать [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable), но ещё лучше - CropCircleTransformation в Picasso, либо аналогичное в Glide.

Answer (score 0):

Обновите версию SDK. Необходима [минимум версия 26.1.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-1-0), судя по [описанию компонента](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/RoundedDrawable.html).

Comment: в том и дело, что SDK обновленный :С

Comment: @Kaija и всё равно не видит этот компонент?